# How to send an ACK response back to server that sent my ColdFusion Page a JSON packet via HTTP POST request

Tags: json, coldfusion, http-post, httpresponsemessage

I am receiving a JSON packet of data from a third party server which I need to process within my ColdFusion page.

The server sending the packet data requires a custom response to be sent back to them to acknowledge that the packet has been received and another once the packet has been successfully processed by my ColdFusion code.

Can anyone point me to a resource that demonstrates how I have my ColdFusion page return the acknowledgement back to the server that sent the packet via HTTP Post request?

Comment: What is the specification of the response?

Comment: Is your ColdFusion page a `.cfm` or `.cfc` file? If it is a `.cfm` file then any output generated by the page will be the return value. If it is a `.cfc` file then you specifically set what to return by using `cfreturn ` _some value or some variable_.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, i am not sure if you understand what i am needing. the output i need which is a generated ack response needs to be send back to the server who send the http post request to acknolwedge to the server that the http post request they send has been 1 received and 2 successfully processed by my page without any errors

Comment: You should write an answer that includes some of what you did so that some one in the future can know how to fix this kind of issue.